# 7zip add files to archive without specifing archive name?

Tags: compression, 7zip

What I mean here is that if I have a few files and folders in a directory

eg:
file.txt
folder1

I would like to compress them all to become:

eg:
file.zip
folder1.zip

Without having to specify the archive name. My current syntax is:
`7z a * -an -tzip`

Which just creates a folder full of no-named zip-files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash loop and a parameter expansion to do that:

```
for i in *; do
7z a -tzip "${i%.*}.zip" "$i"
done
```

Which gives the following:

```
$ ls
file.txt  file.zip  folder1/  folder1.zip
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for more about bash expansion. Here, we use `%` to remove the extension.